# Audio recording with timer

Tags: iphone

I want to take a photo and as soon as i do that, the audio should start recording automatically for say, 3 seconds.

Those 3 seconds should be counted down by a **timer** which appears on the left side of the screen, after the photo is taken.

So, then i have to **combine the image and audio together** and save it in a **private directory**.

Could someone tell me how do i do this by using the **AVFoundation** and **Audio Toolbox** frameworks?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially relating to asking questions. Remember, we are here to help, not to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally work with `AVFoundation` so I don't know the exact method/class names (I filled in my own), but a workaround to this would be having a recurring `NSTimer` beginning when the recording originally starts. Something like this:

```
@interface
int rec_time;
NSTimer *timer;
Recorder *recorder;
@end

@implementation 
-(void)beginRecording {
    [recorder startRecording];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(recordingTime)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
}

-(int)recordingTime {
    if (rec_time >= 10) {
        [recorder endRecording];
        [timer invalidate];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You recorded for too long!";
        return;
    }

    rec_time = rec_time + 1;

}
@end
```

Also

AVAudioRecorder has the following method:

```
- (BOOL)recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I think that will do the trick!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008238

Comment: Thanks a lot...this is only for recording the audio for a certain no of seconds with NSTimer in place. How can i combine the image that i've captured and the audio i've recorded into a single file? Also, i dont want it to be saved in the default directory, but in my private directory.